# Aligator: Pathway analysis fortran program crash with "Segmentation fault"

Tags: fortran

I try to run Aligator (http://x004.psycm.uwcm.ac.uk/~peter/) but it fails on my 64-bit Linux machine. When running aligator as stated in the document-file http://x004.psycm.uwcm.ac.uk/~peter/README_ALIGATOR.doc) I get this error:

```
./aligator < aligator.run > out.txt

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7FDCD5079577
#1  0x7FDCD5079B7E
#2  0x7FDCD457DCAF
#3  0x401DBF in MAIN__ at aligator.f:?
Segmentation fault
```

I have a feeling that this fortran-software was written for 32-bit system, and that's why I also had to compile the aligator.f like this:

```
f77 aligator.f -mcmodel=large -o aligator
```

The source-code of aligator.f:

```
CHARACTER*50 INFILE,OUTFILE
      CHARACTER*8 PROCNAM(5),PXN
      INTEGER JSNP(6000000,25),NSNP(6000000)
      INTEGER ISNP(6000000)
      INTEGER ILIS(100,2)
      INTEGER NGS(1000000),IDSNP(1000000)
      INTEGER IGS(1000000,25)
      INTEGER ICH(20000),IGOC(20000)
      INTEGER IDGE(30000),IPFC(35000,2)
      INTEGER IDGO(20000),NGC(30000)
      INTEGER JDGO(20000),MGC(30000)
      INTEGER MPFC(20000),MCG(30000),NCG(30000)
      INTEGER IGC(30000,1000),JSCO(20000)
      INTEGER JGC(30000,1000),ISGSNP(200000)
      INTEGER KSCO(50000,10000),MSCO(20000)
      INTEGER NUMSIG(3,5)
      INTEGER MUMSIG(3,5),ISLIM(200)
      INTEGER ISCO(20000),MUM(20000),NUN(20000)
      REAL PR(20000),CRIT(3),CUM(1000001),QR(20000)
      REAL ZR(20000),YR(3,5),GM(20000),QZ(5),PMIN(5)
      REAL DUM(1000001),QMIN(5)
      REAL*8 QP(20000),CHX,RU(20000),QQ(20000)
      REAL*8 XX,ST,YY
      REAL*8 GETRAN
      EXTERNAL GETRAN,QUIKSORT
      OPEN(10,FILE='allsnp_gene_NCBI_0KB.txt')
C     THIS FILE CONTAINS A LIST OF ALL SNPs ANNOTATED
C     BY THE GENES THEY LIE WITHIN (NCBI ID NUMBERS)
      OPEN(25,FILE='allsnp_gene_NCBI_0KB.list')
      OPEN(11,FILE='gene_go_17_03_09.dat')
      OPEN(12,FILE='pfc_17_03_09.dat')
      READ(*,*) INFILE
      READ(*,*) OUTFILE
      OPEN(14,FILE=INFILE)
      OPEN(15,FILE=OUTFILE)
      READ(*,*) NSNPLIST
      READ(*,*) DRIT
      READ(*,*) NWIN
      READ(*,*) NREP
      READ(*,*) ST
      NSG=5770877
C     TOTAL NUMBER OF SNPS IN FILE allsnp_gene_NCBI_0KB.txt
      NGO=754498
C     TOTAL NUMBER OF GENE/GO CATEGORY ASSIGNMENTS 
      NPFC=28339
C     TOTAL NUMBER OF GO CATEGORIES WITH NAMES/FUNCTION DATA
      PROCNAM(1)='ALL CATS'
      PROCNAM(2)='CELLULAR'
      PROCNAM(3)='FUNCTION'
      PROCNAM(4)='PROCESS '
      PROCNAM(5)='PRO+FUNC'
      CRIT(1)=0.05
      CRIT(2)=0.01
      CRIT(3)=0.001
      NUM=0
      DO 873 I=1,NPFC
      READ(12,*) (IPFC(I,K),K=1,2)
873   CONTINUE
      DO 871 I=1,1000000
      NGS(I)=0
871   CONTINUE
      DO 872 I=1,30000
      MGC(I)=0
      MCG(I)=0
872   CONTINUE
      DO 604 I=10,99
      READ(25,*) II,ILIS(I,1),ILIS(I,2)
604   CONTINUE
C     READING IN START AND END POINTS ON THE COMPLETE LIST OF SNPS WHOSE
C     RS NUMBERS START WITH 10, 11, .... 99
C     TO MAKE IT FASTER TO LOCATE THE SNPS USED IN A PARTICULAR STUDY.
      MMSP=0
      DO 503 I=1,NSG
      READ(10,*) ISNP(I),NSNP(I),(JSNP(I,K),K=1,NSNP(I))
503   CONTINUE
C     READS IN COMPLETE LIST OF SNPS WITHIN GENES
      MGE=0
      MSP=0
      DO 605 I=1,NSNPLIST
C     THIS SECTION READS IN THE SNPS USED IN THE STUDY BEING ANALYSED
C     CHECKS THEM AGAINST THE TOTAL LIST OF SNPS WITHIN GENES
C     TO CREATE A LIST OF SNPS WITHIN GENES AND THE GENES WITHIN WHICH THEY LIE
      READ(14,*) II,PP
      RS=REAL(II)
      RX=LOG10(RS)
      IX=INT(RX)-1
      RJ=REAL(IX)
      IC=INT(RS/(10**RJ))
      IUS=0
      DO 696 J=ILIS(IC,1),ILIS(IC,2)
      IF (II.EQ.ISNP(J)) THEN
        IUS=J
        GOTO 697
      ENDIF
696   CONTINUE
697   CONTINUE
      IF (IUS.EQ.0) THEN
        GOTO 605
      ENDIF
      MSP=MSP+1
      IDSNP(MSP)=ISNP(IUS)
      NGS(MSP)=NSNP(IUS)
      DO 698 J=1,NSNP(IUS) 
      JGX=JSNP(IUS,J)
      JNE=0
      DO 802 II=1,MGE
      IF (JGX.EQ.IDGE(II)) THEN
        JNE=II
      ENDIF
802   CONTINUE
      IF (JNE.EQ.0) THEN
        MGE=MGE+1
        IDGE(MGE)=JGX
        JNE=MGE
      ENDIF
      IGS(MSP,J)=JNE
698   CONTINUE
      IF (PP.LT.DRIT) THEN
        NUM=NUM+1
        ISGSNP(NUM)=MSP
      ENDIF
C     CREATES LIST OF SIGNIFICANT SNPS WITH P-val < SPECIFIED CRITERION
699   CONTINUE
605   CONTINUE
      DUM(1)=0.0
      DO 603 I=1,MSP
      DUM(I+1)=DUM(I)+(1.0/FLOAT(MSP))
603   CONTINUE
      DUM(MSP+1)=1.0
      PRINT*,'SNPS READ'
      PRINT*,'#SNPS = ',MSP
      PRINT*,'#GENES = ',MGE
      DO 502 I=1,NGO
      READ(11,*) JGX,IID
      INE=0
      DO 842 II=1,MGE
      IF (JGX.EQ.IDGE(II)) THEN
        INE=II
        GOTO 937
      ENDIF
842   CONTINUE
937   CONTINUE
      IF (INE.EQ.0) THEN
        GOTO 502
      ENDIF
      JNE=0
      DO 602 II=1,MMGO
      IF (IID.EQ.JDGO(II)) THEN
        JNE=II
      ENDIF
602   CONTINUE
      IF (JNE.EQ.0) THEN
        MMGO=MMGO+1
C       PRINT*,MMGO,IID
        JDGO(MMGO)=IID
        JNE=MMGO
      ENDIF
      INF=0
      DO 722 J=1,MGC(INE)
      IF (JNE.EQ.JGC(INE,J)) THEN
        INF=J
      ENDIF
722   CONTINUE
      IF (INF.EQ.0) THEN
        MGC(INE)=MGC(INE)+1
        MCG(JNE)=MCG(JNE)+1
        JGC(INE,MGC(INE))=JNE
      ENDIF
C     JGC CONTAINS ALL GO GATEGORY MEMBERSHIPS FOR EACH GENE
502   CONTINUE
      MGO=0
      DO 607 I=1,MMGO
C     THIS SECTION REMOVES GO CATEGORIES WITH FEWER THAN 3 GENES
C     OR MORE THAN 5000 (USER CAN EDIT AND RECOMPILE IF DESIRED)
      IF (MCG(I).LT.3.OR.MCG(I).GT.5000) THEN
        ICH(I)=0
        GOTO 607
      ENDIF
      MGO=MGO+1
      NCG(MGO)=MCG(I)
      IDGO(MGO)=JDGO(I)
      ICH(I)=MGO
      IPF=0
      DO 874 J=1,NPFC
      IF (IDGO(MGO).EQ.IPFC(J,1)) THEN
        IPF=J
        GOTO 931
      ENDIF
874   CONTINUE
931   CONTINUE
      IF (IPF.EQ.0) THEN
        PRINT*,'MISSING CATEGORY ',IDGO(MGO)
      ELSE
        MPFC(MGO)=IPFC(IPF,2)
      ENDIF
607   CONTINUE
      DO 609 I=1,MGE
      NGC(I)=0
      NGC(I)=0
      DO 608 J=1,MGC(I)
      JX=JGC(I,J)
      NN=ICH(JX)
      IF (NN.NE.0) THEN
        NGC(I)=NGC(I)+1
        IGC(I,NGC(I))=NN
      ENDIF
608   CONTINUE
609   CONTINUE
      PRINT*,'CATS READ'
      PRINT*,'No.CATS = ',MGO
      NMA=0
      JMA=0
      DO 226 I=1,MGE
      IF (NGC(I).GE.NMA) THEN
        NMA=NGC(I)
        JMA=I
      ENDIF
226   CONTINUE
      PRINT*,'MAX #CATS PER GENE = ',NMA
      PRINT*,'GENE ID ',IDGE(JMA)
      NMA=0
      JMA=0
      DO 2 I=1,MSP
      IF (NGS(I).GE.NMA) THEN
        NMA=NGS(I)
        JMA=I
      ENDIF
2     CONTINUE
      PRINT*,'NO. SNPS IN STUDY = ',NSNPLIST
      PRINT*,'NO. SNPS IN GENES = ',MSP
      PRINT*,'MAX #GENES PER SNP = ',NMA
      PRINT*,'SNP ID ',IDSNP(JMA)
      NMA=0
      JMA=0
      DO 3 I=1,MGO
      IF (NGC(I).GE.NMA) THEN
        NMA=NGC(I)
        JMA=I
      ENDIF
3     CONTINUE
      DO 987 IY=1,20000
      ISCO(IY)=0
      JSCO(IY)=0
987   CONTINUE
      DO 587 IY=1,3
      DO 787 IZ=1,5
      NUMSIG(IY,IZ)=0
787   CONTINUE
587   CONTINUE
      JGE=0
      DO 14 I=1,NUM
      DO 198 J=1,20000
      IGOC(J)=0
198   CONTINUE
      KU=ISGSNP(I)
C     GET THE ID OF EACH SIGNIFICANT SNP
      DO 16 J=1,NGS(KU)
      ICG=IGS(KU,J)
C     WHAT GENES DOES IT LIE IN ?
      IUS=0
      DO 26 K=1,JGE
      IF (ICG.EQ.JSCO(K)) THEN
        IUS=K
      ENDIF
26    CONTINUE
C     IS THIS GENE ALREADY ON THE LIST ?
      IF (IUS.EQ.0) THEN
        JGE=JGE+1
        JSCO(JGE)=ICG
C       ADD GENE TO LIST
        DO 18 KK=1,NGC(ICG)
        K=IGC(ICG,KK)
        IF (IGOC(K).EQ.0) THEN
          ISCO(K)=ISCO(K)+1
          IGOC(K)=1
        ENDIF
C       INCREASE THE COUNT OF SIGNIFICANT GENES FOR ALL GO CATEGORIES 
C       CONTAINING THIS GENE BY 1 - BUT ONLY IF THIS SNP HASN'T ALREADY
C       CONTRIBUTED A GENE TO THIS CATEGORY. IF A SNP LIES
C       IN SEVERAL OVERLAPPING GENES ALL IN THE SAME GO CATEGORY,
C       THIS PREVENTS ALL THE GENES BEING COUNTED SEPARATELY. 
18      CONTINUE
      ENDIF
16    CONTINUE
14    CONTINUE
      PRINT*,'P-VALUE CRITERION FOR DEFINING SIGNIFICANT SNPS = ',DRIT
      PRINT*,'NUMBER OF GENES WITH SIGNIFICANT SNPS = ',JGE
      PRINT*,'NUMBER OF SIMULATED REPLICATE GENE-LISTS = ',NWIN
      PRINT*,'NUMBER OF BOOTSTRAP STUDIES = ',NREP
      DO 979 IT=1,NWIN
      PRINT*,'SIMULATED REPLICATE GENELIST',IT
      KRE=1
      DO 887 IY=1,10000
      JSCO(IY)=0
      GM(IY)=0
      KSCO(IT,IY)=0
887   CONTINUE
      KGE=0
666   CONTINUE
      YY=GETRAN(XX,ST)
      R=REAL(XX)
      KU=0
      DO 551 K=1,MSP
      IF (R.GE.DUM(K).AND.R.LT.DUM(K+1)) THEN
        KU=K
      ENDIF
551   CONTINUE
C     SELECT A RANDOM SNP
      DO 298 J=1,20000
      IGOC(J)=0
298   CONTINUE
      DO 116 J=1,NGS(KU)
      ICG=IGS(KU,J)
C     WHAT GENES DOES THE SNP LIE IN ?
      IUS=0
      DO 216 K=1,KGE
      IF (ICG.EQ.JSCO(K)) THEN
        IUS=K
      ENDIF
216   CONTINUE
C     GENE ALREADY ON LIST ?
C     PRINT*,II,NID-I,IDJ,IUS,ICG
      IF (IUS.EQ.0) THEN
        KGE=KGE+1
C       PRINT*,IT,KGE
        IF (KGE.GT.JGE) THEN
           GOTO 994
        ENDIF
C       GENELIST REACHED THE SAME LENGTH AS THE ORIGINAL ?
        JSCO(KGE)=ICG
        DO 118 KK=1,NGC(ICG)
        K=IGC(ICG,KK)
        IF (IGOC(K).EQ.0) THEN
          KSCO(IT,K)=KSCO(IT,K)+1
          IGOC(K)=1
        ENDIF
118     CONTINUE
C       ADD 1 TO EACH GO CATEGORY CONTAINING THE GENE (SEE ABOVE)
      ENDIF
116   CONTINUE
      GOTO 666
994   CONTINUE
979   CONTINUE
      DO 812 IX=1,5
      PMIN(IX)=99.0
812   CONTINUE
      NSCA=0
      DO 22 I=1,MGO
      NMP=MPFC(I)
      IF (ISCO(I).LE.1) THEN
        GOTO 22
      ENDIF
C     ONLY COUNT GO CATEGORIES WITH TWO OR MORE SIGNIFICANT GENES
      PR(I)=0
      ZR(I)=0
      RU(I)=0.0d0
      CUM(1)=0
      DO 32 J=1,NWIN
      IF (ISCO(I).LE.KSCO(J,I)) THEN
        PR(I)=PR(I)+(1.0/FLOAT(NWIN))
      ENDIF
C     CATEGORY-SPECIFIC P-VALUE = NUMBER OF SIMULATED GENELISTS
C     WHERE THE SCORE FOR THE CATEGORY (KSCO) IS AT LEAST AS HIGH
C     AS THAT IN THE REAL DATA (ISCO)
      CUM(J+1)=CUM(J)+(1.0/FLOAT(NWIN))
      GM(I)=GM(I)+(FLOAT(KSCO(J,I))/FLOAT(NWIN))
C     CALCULATING EXPECTED NUMBER OF SIGNIFICANT GENES IN THE CATEGORY
32    CONTINUE
      CUM(NWIN+1)=1.0
      IF (PR(I).LT.PMIN(1)) THEN
        PMIN(1)=PR(I)
      ENDIF
      DO 813 J=1,3
      IF (NMP.EQ.J.AND.PR(I).LE.PMIN(J+1)) THEN
        PMIN(J+1)=PR(I)
      ENDIF
813   CONTINUE
      IF (NMP.GE.2.AND.PR(I).LE.PMIN(5)) THEN
        PMIN(5)=PR(I)
      ENDIF
C     CALCULATING MINIMUM P-VALUES FOR CATEGORIES OF EACH FUNCTIONAL TYPE
      DO 33 J=1,3
      IF (PR(I).LE.CRIT(J)) THEN
        NUMSIG(J,1)=NUMSIG(J,1)+1
        NUMSIG(J,NMP+1)=NUMSIG(J,NMP+1)+1
        IF (NMP.GE.2) THEN
          NUMSIG(J,5)=NUMSIG(J,5)+1
        ENDIF
      ENDIF
C     COUNTING NUMBER OF CATEGORIES REACHING A GIVEN CATEGORY-SPECIFIC P-VALUE
33    CONTINUE
      QP(I)=DBLE(PR(I))
22    CONTINUE
      NBOOT=NWIN
      DO 716 IC=1,3
      DO 816 ID=1,5
      YR(IC,ID)=0
816   CONTINUE
716   CONTINUE
      DO 819 I=1,5
      QZ(I)=0
819   CONTINUE
      DO 51 I=1,NREP
C     PRINT*,I
C     PERFORMING REPLICATE "STUDIES" TO GET SIGNIFICANCE OF NUMBERS OF 
C     SIGNIFICANTLY OVER-REPRESENTED CATEGORIES
      YY=GETRAN(XX,ST)
      R=REAL(XX)
      IYS=0
      DO 53 K=1,NWIN
      IF (R.GE.CUM(K).AND.R.LT.CUM(K+1)) THEN
        IYS=K
      ENDIF
53    CONTINUE
C     CHOOSE A REPLICATE GENE-LIST TO ACT AS THE "REAL DATA"
      DO 54 K=1,MGO
      MSCO(K)=KSCO(IYS,K)
      QR(K)=0
54    CONTINUE
      DO 58 K=1,3
      DO 589 KK=1,5
      MUMSIG(K,KK)=0
589   CONTINUE
58    CONTINUE
      DO 52 J=1,NBOOT
528   CONTINUE
      YY=GETRAN(XX,ST)
      R=REAL(XX)
      JYS=0
      DO 55 K=1,NWIN
      IF (R.GE.CUM(K).AND.R.LT.CUM(K+1)) THEN
        JYS=K
      ENDIF
55    CONTINUE
      IF (JYS.EQ.IYS) THEN
        GOTO 528
      ENDIF
C     SELECT REPLICATE GENE LISTS (WITH REPLACEMENT)
      DO 56 K=1,MGO
      IF (MSCO(K).LE.KSCO(JYS,K)) THEN
        QR(K)=QR(K)+(1.0/FLOAT(NBOOT))
      ENDIF
C     OBTAIN CATEGORY-SPECIFIC P-VALUES FOR THE "REAL DATA"
56    CONTINUE
52    CONTINUE
      DO 814 K=1,5
      QMIN(K)=99.0
814   CONTINUE
      DO 57 K=1,MGO
      NMP=MPFC(K)
      IF (MSCO(K).LE.1) THEN
        GOTO 57
      ENDIF
      JGG=IDGO(K)
      IF (QR(K).LT.QMIN(1)) THEN
        QMIN(1)=QR(K)
      ENDIF
      DO 815 JX=1,3
      IF (NMP.EQ.JX.AND.QR(K).LE.QMIN(JX+1)) THEN
        QMIN(JX+1)=QR(K)
      ENDIF
815   CONTINUE
      IF (NMP.GE.2.AND.QR(K).LE.QMIN(5)) THEN
        QMIN(5)=QR(K)
      ENDIF
C     OBTAIN MINIMUM P-VALUES FOR CATEGORIES OF VARIOUS FUNCTIONAL TYPES
      DO 63 JJ=1,3
      IF (QR(K).LE.CRIT(JJ)) THEN
        MUMSIG(JJ,1)=MUMSIG(JJ,1)+1
        MUMSIG(JJ,NMP+1)=MUMSIG(JJ,NMP+1)+1
        IF (NMP.GE.2) THEN
          MUMSIG(JJ,5)=MUMSIG(JJ,5)+1
        ENDIF
      ENDIF
C     OBTAIN NUMBERS OF CATEGORIES WITH CATEGORY-SPECIFIC P-VALUES LESS THAN
C     VARIOUS CRITERIA
63    CONTINUE
57    CONTINUE
      DO 67 K=1,MGO
      IF (ISCO(K).LE.1) THEN
        GOTO 67
      ENDIF
      IF (PR(K).GE.QMIN(1)) THEN
        ZR(K)=ZR(K)+(1.0/FLOAT(NREP))
      ENDIF
C     PROBABILITY THAT ANY CATEGORY-SPECIFIC P-VALUE IN A STUDY WHERE THERE
C     IS NO FUNCTIONAL ASSOCIATION (i.e. RANDOMLY-SELECTED "REAL DATA") IS
C     LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO THE P-VALUE OF A GIVEN CATEGORY IN THE ORIGINAL
C     DATASET (i.e. A STUDY-WIDE P-VALUE CORRECTED FOR TESTING MULTIPLE NON-
C     INDEPENDENT CATEGORIES)
      DO 77 KK=1,MGO
      IF (MSCO(KK).LE.1) THEN
        GOTO 77
      ENDIF
      IF (PR(K).GE.QR(KK)) THEN
        RU(K)=RU(K)+(1.0d0/DFLOAT(NREP))
      ENDIF
C     EXPECTED NUMBER OF CATEGORIES PER STUDY WITH CATEGORY-SPECIFIC P-vALUES
C     LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO THAT OF A GIVEN CATEGORY IN THE ORIGINAL DATASET
77    CONTINUE
67    CONTINUE
      DO 817 JJ=1,5
      IF (QMIN(JJ).LE.PMIN(JJ)) THEN
        QZ(JJ)=QZ(JJ)+(1.0/FLOAT(NREP))
      ENDIF
C     PROBABILITY THAT THE MINIMUM CATEGORY-SPECIFIC P-VALUE IN A STUDY WHERE THERE
C     IS NO FUNCTIONAL ASSOCIATION (i.e. RANDOMLY-SELECTED "REAL DATA") IS
C     LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO THE MINIMUM CATEGORY-SPECIFIC P-VALUE IN THE ORIGINAL
C     DATA
817   CONTINUE
      DO 64 JJ=1,3
      DO 642 JH=1,5
      IF (MUMSIG(JJ,JH).GE.NUMSIG(JJ,JH)) THEN
        YR(JJ,JH)=YR(JJ,JH)+(1.0/FLOAT(NREP))
      ENDIF
C     PROBABILITY THAN THE NUMBER OF CATEGORIES REACHING SIGNIFICANCE IN A STUDY
C     WHERE THERE IS NO FUNCTIONAL ASSOCIATION (i.e. RANDOMLY-SELECTED "REAL DATA")
C     IS LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO THAT IN THE ORIGINAL DATA (i.e. TESTING FOR A
C     SIGNIFICANTLY LARGE NUMBER OF OVER-REPRESENTED CATEGORIES)
642   CONTINUE
64    CONTINUE
51    CONTINUE
      DO 712 IT=1,MGO
      IF (ISCO(IT).EQ.0) THEN
        QP(IT)=1d0+DBLE(GM(IT))
      ENDIF
712   CONTINUE
      X=QUIKSORT(QP,MGO,MUM)
      DO 23 I=1,MGO
      J=MUM(I)
      NMP=MPFC(J)
      PXN=PROCNAM(NMP+1)
      JG=IDGO(J)
      JH=ISCO(J)
      IF (ISCO(J).LE.1) THEN
        GOTO 23
      ENDIF
C     ONLY COUNT GO CATEGORIES WITH TWO OR MORE SIGNIFICANT GENES
      WRITE(15,44) JG,PXN,JH,JGE,NCG(J),MGE,GM(J),PR(J),ZR(J),RU(J)
23    CONTINUE
      WRITE(15,*)
      WRITE(15,*)
      DO 691 ISS=1,5
      WRITE(15,*) PROCNAM(ISS)
      WRITE(15,*)
      WRITE(15,*) 'MIN P =',PMIN(ISS),' SIG = ',QZ(ISS)
      WRITE(15,*)
      DO 69 IS=1,3
      WRITE(15,*) 'NO. OF P<',CRIT(IS),' =',NUMSIG(IS,ISS)
      WRITE(15,*) 'SIG = ',YR(IS,ISS)
69    CONTINUE
      WRITE(15,*)
691   CONTINUE
      CLOSE(15)
44    FORMAT(I8,2X,A8,3(2X,I5),2X,I5,2X,F7.2,2X,F7.5,2X,F6.4,2X,F9.2)
      STOP
      END

      REAL*8 FUNCTION GETRAN(X,S)
      REAL*8 X,S,A,B,SN,SS,RN
      INTEGER IS
      A=7D0**5
      B=(2D0**31)-1
      SN=S*A
      IS=INT(SN/B)
      SS=DFLOAT(IS)
C     PRINT*,SN,SS,IS
      RN=SN-(SS*B)
      S=RN
      X=S/B
      GETRAN=1D0
      RETURN
      END

      REAL FUNCTION QUIKSORT(RLOD,NLO,NUM)
      REAL*8 RLOD(20000)
      REAL*8 SORT1(20000),SORT2(20000),SORT3(20000)
      INTEGER NUM(20000),NUM1(20000),NUM2(20000)
      DO 5 I=1,NLO
      SORT1(I)=-1000.0D0
      NUM1(I)=0
5     CONTINUE
      DO 10 I=1,NLO
      XLO=RLOD(I)
C     PRINT*,XLO
      DO 20 J=NLO+1-I,NLO
      IF (XLO.GE.SORT1(J)) THEN
C       PRINT*,XLO,SORT1(J),J
        IPOS=J
      ENDIF
20    CONTINUE
C     PRINT*,IPOS
      SORT2(IPOS)=XLO
      NUM2(IPOS)=I
      DO 30 K=2,IPOS
      SORT2(K-1)=SORT1(K)
      NUM2(K-1)=NUM1(K)
30    CONTINUE
      DO 40 K=IPOS+1,NLO
      SORT2(K)=SORT1(K)
      NUM2(K)=NUM1(K)
40    CONTINUE
      DO 50 L=1,NLO
      NUM1(L)=NUM2(L)
      SORT1(L)=SORT2(L)
C     PRINT*,L,SORT1(L)
50    CONTINUE
10    CONTINUE
      DO 60 I=1,NLO
      NUM(I)=NUM1(I)
60    CONTINUE
      QUIKSORT=1.0
      RETURN
      END
```

Because I am not a fortran-coder, I wonder if this code can be changed to fully support a 64-bit system?

**EDIT:**
I tried compiling like this:

```
gfortran aligator.f -o aligator -g -fcheck=all -fbacktrace
```

with those errors:

```
/tmp/ccbJsCPS.o: In function `MAIN__':
/home/alexsson/Programs/Aligator/aligator.f:354:(.text+0x628a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
/home/alexsson/Programs/Aligator/aligator.f:355:(.text+0x62ff): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
/home/alexsson/Programs/Aligator/aligator.f:356:(.text+0x6374): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
/home/alexsson/Programs/Aligator/aligator.f:357:(.text+0x6380): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
/home/alexsson/Programs/Aligator/aligator.f:360:(.text+0x65c5): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
/home/alexsson/Programs/Aligator/aligator.f:360:(.text+0x65eb): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
/home/alexsson/Programs/Aligator/aligator.f:365:(.text+0x66c3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
/home/alexsson/Programs/Aligator/aligator.f:365:(.text+0x66e9): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
/home/alexsson/Programs/Aligator/aligator.f:369:(.text+0x697d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
/home/alexsson/Programs/Aligator/aligator.f:370:(.text+0x69ee): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
/home/alexsson/Programs/Aligator/aligator.f:371:(.text+0x6a6a): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Im not sure if I get any smarter...

**Solution:**
Thanks to tkoenig, the solution is to change the source-code of aligator.f to this: http://pastebin.com/tnYhuba3

It works on my Slackware 64-bit current (multilib enabled) - system with 16 GB RAM.

Comment: Compile with a recent gfortran compiler with the options `-g -fcheck=all -fbacktrace` and run the resulting program. This will give you a clearer error message, at least

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, please see my post above for results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some **really** large arrays in there which cause problems with a 32-bit addressing mode.  If you make the arrays allocatable and allocate them at the start of the program, as with with

```
  CHARACTER*50 INFILE,OUTFILE
  CHARACTER*8 PROCNAM(5),PXN
  integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: jsnp
  integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: nsnp, isnp
  INTEGER ILIS(100,2)
  INTEGER NGS(1000000),IDSNP(1000000)
  INTEGER IGS(1000000,25)
  INTEGER ICH(20000),IGOC(20000)
  INTEGER IDGE(30000),IPFC(35000,2)
  INTEGER IDGO(20000),NGC(30000)
  INTEGER JDGO(20000),MGC(30000)
  INTEGER MPFC(20000),MCG(30000),NCG(30000)
  integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: igc, jgc, ksco
  INTEGER JSCO(20000)
  INTEGER ISGSNP(200000)
  INTEGER MSCO(20000)
  INTEGER NUMSIG(3,5)
  INTEGER MUMSIG(3,5),ISLIM(200)
  INTEGER ISCO(20000),MUM(20000),NUN(20000)
  REAL PR(20000),CRIT(3),CUM(1000001),QR(20000)
  REAL ZR(20000),YR(3,5),GM(20000),QZ(5),PMIN(5)
  REAL DUM(1000001),QMIN(5)
  REAL*8 QP(20000),CHX,RU(20000),QQ(20000)
  REAL*8 XX,ST,YY
  REAL*8 GETRAN
  EXTERNAL GETRAN,QUIKSORT
  allocate(JSNP(6000000,25))
  allocate(NSNP(6000000), ISNP(6000000))
  allocate(IGC(30000,1000),JGC(30000,1000),KSCO(50000,10000))
```

this should no longer be a concern.

I cannot check this because of lack of memory.

Depending on the range of the values you need to use for the INTEGER, it might also be interesting to change the default integer to a two-byte or one-byte kind, as in

```
  integer, parameter :: i2 = selected_int_kind(4) ! select range of at least 10000, usually translates into two bytes
  integer(kind=i2), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: jsnp
```

or

```
  integer, parameter :: i1 = selected_int_kind(2) ! one-byte integer
```

This can lead to significant savings in memory and speed.

Comment: Thank you. I could compile aligator without mcmodel-flag. However, I still get the same error when running it... This software seems hopeless.

Comment: If I change integer to two-byte I get this:
At line 79 of file aligator.f (unit = 10, file = 'allsnp_gene_NCBI_0KB.txt')
Fortran runtime error: Integer overflow while reading item 1

Comment: Line 79:       READ(10,*) ISNP(I),NSNP(I),(JSNP(I,K),K=1,NSNP(I))

Comment: OK, so the two-byte integer idea does not work.   It would be interesting to see what compiling with -fcheck=all -g and then running would give you.  Do you have enough memory? I also notice that there are quite a few implicitly declared variables (adding IMPLICIT NONE at the top will show you quite a few).  Finally, declaring fixed bounds like 600000 (or whatever) is quite bad. So... yes, not the best piece of dusty-deck software I have seen.

Comment: Interesting, I get this:
./aligator < aligator.run > out.txt           
At line 152 of file aligator.f
Fortran runtime error: Index '20001' of dimension 1 of array 'jdgo' above upper bound of 20000.

Hmm, this software is indeed badly written.

Comment: Do you have some tips how I can unlimit the bounds?

Thank you for your help so far, really appreciated.

Comment: And btw, I have 16 GB memory, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: I changed jdgo (INTEGER JDGO(600000000),MGC(30000)) to upper bound 6000000, but still get: At line 152 of file aligator.f
Fortran runtime error: Index '6000001' of dimension 1 of array 'jdgo' above upper bound of 6000000

...

Comment: Some further investigation with "-Wall -O" shows that the variables `ipos` and `mmgo`  could be used uninitialized.  Some older compilers initialized all variables to zero.  You could try doing this manually and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your sentence. I try to initialize with 0, let's see what happens.

Comment: Yes, that did it! By initializing IPOS and MMGO with 0 it now works. Thank you!